# How do I get User To Show Up AWS IAM Identity Center Under AWS Accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iam-identity-center

Steps to reproduce: Using the AWS Console, I did the following under IAM Identity Center:

1. Under root account: I added a user named "PID-REDACTED-"st (see screenshot, please)
2. I logged in as the said user in an incognito browser - logs in fine
3. Under the root account, I navigated to Multi-account permissions and AWS Accounts.

Observed result: I can not see the user I added under Multi-account permissions.
Expected result: I expected to see the user I added under Multi-account permissions. How can I get them to show up there?

Or am I not tracking on the tutorial [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/getting-started.html)?

THANK YOU!! In advance :-)
[image: I can see user I added under "Users"]

[image: I can not see user i added under Multi-accounts-permissions]

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who might encounter this, you have to select a user in the above "Organizational structure" tree and then click on the "Assign Users or Groups" CTA (call to action at the top right side) and then you will see the users under the "Users" section.

Also, sometimes, we may need to make sure we're adding users at the right place as per the `Identity Source`.

[image: Identity Source]